# Why can't i drag and drop in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is website: https://html5demos.com/drag/
And this is my code perform drag and drop element using java, chrome and selenium 3.141.59

```
    By dustBin = By.xpath("//div[@id=\"bin\"]");
    By one = By.xpath("//a[@id=\"one\"]");

    WebElement From = driver.findElement(one);
    WebElement To = driver.findElement(dustBin);

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.dragAndDrop(From,To).build().perform();
    actions.clickAndHold(From).moveToElement(To).build().perform();
    actions.dragAndDropBy(From,176,260).build().perform();
```

When I run test with TestNG the element is not moving to dustBin. So I dont know why. Any one help me resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use findElementById to find locator instead of xpatch.

**Try this one:**

```
WebElement sourceLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("one"));
                //To get target locator
WebElement targetLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("bin"));
```

Comment: I have tried but not working actions.dragAndDrop(sourceLocator,targetLocator).build().perform();